# Opening a workbook from an http file path

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

forgive me for mistakes it's my first time posting a question.

I'm trying to open a workbook from VBA that is located on my company's intranet. I've used this same strategy before but with a file path. When I use the code below I get a:

"Run-time error '424':
 Object required"

```
Sub openWorkbook()

    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = Range("AF10").Value

    Workbook.Open (fileName)

End Sub
```

Cell AF10 contains a text string "http:// intranet/...\FileName.xlsm"

I'm not tied to any of the functions, I'm just new to this and wasn't able to find anything better online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the backslash, shouldn't it be `workbooks.open filename`?

Comment: Naturally, our intranet went down a few moments after I posted this, so I won't be able to test answers/suggestions until tomorrow. Sorry :(

Comment: Thank you, it was just the carelessness of missing the "s" in workbooks. It still doesn't work, but that's a different problem. Thanks again.